# Deploying IPSWs to hundreds of Mac Minis

Tags: ios, itunes, network, mac-mini, ipsw

So, here is my situation,

At work we have 3 benches, each bench has 32 Mac Minis, each connected to a KVM.   We use the Mac Minis to delete the customer data and restore a fresh IPSW to iPods, iPads, iPhones, etc.

Whenever a new update comes out for some iDevice, we need a way to push out the new IPSWs from a central location (right now we are using a Mac Pro running 10.12.5 and a dual 10GbE card connected to a 48 port 1 Gig switch with four SFP+ 10GbE ports.)   The guy who had orginally setup the Mac Mini's used to use a rsync script to copy the new ipsw's to each mac mini, but he also had set each device's IP address statically so he could iterate through all of the IP addresses on the subnet without missing any machines.   We recently had to reimage all of the machines using Deploy Studio, and ended up putting each Mini on DHCP instead of having the IP address set statically - so the old method of using this rsync script has gone out the window.

What are my options for downloading the new IPSWs from apple to a single location, and then having the minis download the files from a local shared folder instead of trying to grab them all from the internet?   As you could imagine, 96 mac minis trying to download a 2-3 GB file from the internet is not really an option.   I read something about the cache server in OS X Server, but I wanted to check with the AskDifferent community to see if anyone had any suggestions for technologies that could help me do this.

Comment: The caching function on MacOS Server sounds like a good idea, but with my limited experience, I don't know if it will work. How are you wiping these machines? Are you using Apple Configurator 2 or a different program? If it's a different program, how/where are you storing the IPSWs?

Comment: We have a custom app written by developers that work for my company that interacts with iTunes and takes the manual steps of restoring a Apple device and automates it.

Comment: But it does all of that through iTunes? (Basically, is iTunes the app that is checking for and would be downloading the IPSW?) If so, I am almost positive (like 95%) that MacOS Server caching would be an answer. Note that the caching server won't PUSH the updates, but it will only need to download the IPSW once. After that, the rest of the Minis can fetch, or "Download", the IPSW from the Mac Pro. If you need a push solution, however, this isn't it, and, depending on budget, you might want to take a look at he Jamf suite -you can deploy packages which will automatically install the IPSW. My 2¢